# SQLite Encryption in Universal Windows Platform C#

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, pragma, sqlite-net

I'm using SQLite.Net-PCL V 3.1.1 as a Nuget package and the VS extension SQLite for Universal Windows Platform 3.13.0.0. and this code in a Windows 10 application in C# and XAML:

```
  private  void ConnectToDB()
    {
        var sqlpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "persons.sqlite");

        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath))
        {
            var res = conn.Execute("PRAGMA key = 'mypass'");

            conn.CreateTable<Person>();
            conn.Insert(Person.NewPersion());
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public static Person NewPersion()
        {
            return new Person() { Uuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "John", Age = 12 };
        }

        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Uuid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

This code actually works, creates a DB and inserts a person. But what is not working is the line

```
var res = conn.Execute("PRAGMA key = 'mypass'");
```

The weird thing is that 3 months ago I got this working, and trying to open a DB without this PRAGMA key use to throw:

```
'file is encrypted or is not a database'
```

Which was perfect because the DB was encrypted. In fact trying to open that DB generated in Windows 10 from SqliteExplorer throws that exact error.

I need to be able to encrypt the DB as before, tried downloading previous libraries of the Extension and the Nuget but no luck. Anybody manages to encrypt a sqlite DB with this code?

Regards.

Comment: If we go by the documentation, [`PRAGMA key` is not part of SQLite proper](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html). There are any number of SQLite extensions that provide encryption which may or may not use this pragma. [SQLiteCrypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm) appears to be one; this may or may not be what you used last time.